# TabBar Change Selected Tab Icon Background Color swiftui

Tags: swiftui, uitabbarcontroller

I have this `TabBArViewController` which has 5 tabs in it.

```
struct TabBarViewController: View {
    @State private var selection = 3
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            TabView(selection:$selection) {
                OffersView()
                    .tabItem ({
                        Image(systemName: "bag").renderingMode(.template)
                        Text("Offers")
                    })
                    .tag(1)
                BalanceView()
                    .tabItem ({
                        Image(systemName: "creditcard").renderingMode(.template)
                        Text("Balance")
                    })
                    .tag(2)
                StepView()
                    .tabItem ({
                        Image(systemName: "figure.walk.circle").renderingMode(.template)
                        Text("Steps")
                    })
                    .tag(3)
                FriendsView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "person.2")
                        Text("Friends")
                    }
                    .tag(4)
                ProfileView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "person")
                        Text("Profile")
                    }
                    .tag(5)
                
            }
            .accentColor(Color("ColorOnboarding"))
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        }
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
}
```

which appears as so

[image]

I want to add a rectangle color to this when a tab bar icon selected in SwiftUI. How can I do it without creating a custom tab bar?

[image]

Comment: You might wanna build your own tab bar for this and not use default .tabItem

Comment: in my question, I stated How can I do it without creating a custom tab bar?

Comment: TabItem only takes Image and Text, so you would need to have this as dynamic Image.